# Fetching binary data using NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to fetch binary data and and a string, and the binary data should be the "setPropertiesToFetch.". I've successfully fetched the string, but when I fetch the binary data it only returns memory addresses and not the actual content.

My current code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:id(id)sender 
{ 
    TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *requestGroups = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [requestGroups setFetchBatchSize:INFINITY];

    [requestGroups setEntity:entity];

    [requestGroups setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

    NSMutableArray *urls = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:self.group.selectedurl];

    [requestGroups setPropertiesToFetch:urls];

    [requestGroups setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    NSError *error;

    self.groups = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestGroups error:&error];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    TBGroupsDetailViewController *detailsController = segue.destinationViewController;

    detailsController.group_name = [self.groups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

As I've said before, is there any way to set the property to fetch as binary data type?

Comment: `NSMutuableArray`?? Please copy/paste the actual compiling code.

Comment: I do not yet understand what you are trying to achieve. How is the "Group" entity defined, and what results to you expect? And `propertiesToFetch` is a list of properties of the entity, why do you have to "unarchive" that?

Comment: The "self.groups" is a NSArray with the fetched objects. I'm expecting the "setPropertiesToFetch" to return something like "http://googleusercontent.com/photo.gif", and I am currently getting memory addresses instead. The "Group" entity has a string and a binary data type.

Comment: `self.groups` should be an NSArray of NSDictionary's. What do you mean by *"getting memory adresses only"*? And what exactly does `urls` contain?

Comment: urls contains an array of urls, e.x. googleusercontent.com/photo1.gif, googleusercontent.com/photo2.gif, googleusercontent.com/photo3.gif. This is the output I get:     name = wtf;
    selectedurl = <62706c69 73743030 >; where selectedurl shoul be the urls such as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the function of `propertiesToFetch`. This is a list of
the attributes (or properties) that you are interested in.
For example, If "Group" is an entity with attributes "a", "b" and "c", then you can set

```
[requestGroups setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"a", @"b"];
[requestGroups setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

and the fetch request will return an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary 
contains the "a" and the "b" attribute of one "Group" object.

If you want to fetch all objects  with a certain property, then you have to add a *predicate*.
For example, to fetch all "Group" objects where the the "url" attribute is in the
given array, you would add the predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url IN %@", urls];
[requestGroups setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thanks :) I understand it more now